# integrate function up to 5th degree

Tags: integration, functions

I am a bit confused integrating the function:

$ f(x)=x \cdot(x-3)^{5}$

Am I right that this is an integration in parts?

Thank you in advance, 
kind regards

Comment: Isn't $x \cdot x^2 = x^3$? Seems like we only need the power rule.

Comment: sry, had some trouble with latech. have corrected it

Comment: I see. Answer below.

Comment: It can ve done in many ways. Integration by parts, $u=x$, $dv=(x-3)^5\,dx$ is one of them, not the easiest.

Comment: could you show it in steps, please?

Answer (score 2):

We see $$\int f(x) dx = \int x(x-3)^5 dx = \int (u+3)u^5 du = \int (u^6 + 3u^5 )du$$ where $u = x-3$. Then $$\int f(x) dx = \frac{u^7}{7} + \frac{u^6}{2} + C = \frac{(x-3)^7}{7} + \frac{(x-3)^6}{2} + C$$

Comment: could you please explain how you replace the first x with u + 3 ? It seems like some kind of substitution but I do not get the way you have done it

Comment: Thisis just a $u$-substitution. If $u = x - 3$, then $x = u+3$. So when making the substitution, $x-3$ becomes $u$ and $x$ becomes $u+3$.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want substitution just use $(x-3)^5=x^5-15x^4+90x^3-270x^2+405x-243$ then multiply by $x$ and the integration is just easy.